# Adding a legend to the Hausdorff Distance plot

Tags: meshlab

I'm using meshlab to measure the deviation between two meshes. Is there any way to add a legend to indicate what distance is indicated by certain colours similar to as below? Thanks

[Colour legend in ABAQUS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcUyF.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes!

just type in the search box "show Histogram" and you will get a legend with value to color mapping (and as a bonus an histogram of the distribution of the values over the mesh. In the image below the color codifies the shape quality of the triangles.

[image]

Comment: As a bonus, try to learn how the quality mapper dialog works. This will allow to change the colors used in the scale and clamp small or big distance values.